# Select all columns, but perform except statement on certain columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a temporary table `#TempJoinTable`

I have two fields in this temptable called `PRODUCT_FAM_ID` and `PRODUCT_ID`, and another two fields called `MANDATORY_CD` and `DISPLAY_CD`.

Basically, I have a list of products stored inside another temporary table. One of these product_fam_id/product_id combinations have been fully tested, so the rows and records for this product combination, say '591'/'103', should be the exact same as the other combinations which I have stored in a 'products to check' temptable. The only thing that should be different are the product_fam_id and product_id values, of course

So I tried the following, but I'm pretty new at SQL and a bit stuck. Any advice at all would be welcome

```
 create table #TempProductsToCheck
(
    ProductFamilyID char(10) NULL,
    ProductID char(10) NULL
)

insert into #TempProductsToCheck (ProductFamilyID, ProductID) values
('591', '98'),
('591', '99'),
('591', '101'),
('591', '102'),
('502', '101'),
('502', '102'),
('591', '100'),
('591', '103'),
('502', '103')
```

The main #TempJoinTable consists of the product fields, and the mandatory_cd, and display_cd

```
select distinct *
from #TempJoinTable
where (product_family_id, product_id) in (select product_family_id, product_id
                                          from #TempProductsToCheck)
and where exists (select distinct MANDATORY_CD, DISPLAY_CD
from #TempJoinTable)

except

select distinct *
from #TempJoinTable
where (product_family_id, product_id) in ('591', '103')
and where exists (select distinct MANDATORY_CD, DISPLAY_CD
from #TempJoinTable)
```

I think this could be done easily enough if I just wanted to return the mandatory_cd and display_cd fields, but I'd instead like to return all of the fields from the #TempJoinTable (the other 2 product fields).

I know that the where exists bit is all wrong, but I can't figure out what other options are there to try

Comment: could you paste your expected output and explain it

Comment: hi, thank you. http://imgur.com/a/vkHLK